# I need to flag a method from a third party library as an error - how?

Tags: c#, interface

I need to figure out a way to fail a particular call on a third party library.  One of the base interfaces has object in the parameter that destroys the ability to typesafe check

I am using DI to inject the following third party interface.

```
public interface IValidator<in T> : IValidator {
   Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(T instance, CancellationToken cancellation = default);
}
```

This third party library also defines it

```
public interface IValidator
{
   Task<ValidationResult> ValidateAsync(object instance, CancellationToken cancellation = default);
}
```

This means the whole process is not typesafe as it reverts back to object.   This means more runtime errors.

Is there a way to write a resharper method to flag all use of the object version of this method?

I would prefer that the library not base the typesafe validator off the not typesafe one but until this can be changed I want to highlight these errors.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this, obviously you could do an *"Advanced Find Using"* in resharper. however i think the only other option is a *Roslyn Code Analyzer* to do static analysis AFAIK, or some *tom-foolery* with reflection and run-time analysis

Comment: @TheGeneral My first thought was a facade that hides the unwanted method... Not particularly "easy" but IMHO preferable to reflection. Where am I wrong? (I am suspicious I probably am)

Comment: @Fildor good point actually, my assumption was there was already a large project built on this. you might want to write up an answer